# Does docker require additional port when try to run container?

Tags: docker, docker-container

In my workplace docker is running behind firewall,  only the port that is meant to serve webpage is excluded by rule.

The container starts but website does not open for same port.

If I host the website from machine running container using python -m SimpleHTTPServer it works.

```
docker container run --restart=always -p 8081: 8082 -it vue-js-app: latest
```

Comment: Can you share the command you run and the port you want to use?

Comment: don't put a space after the colons:  `8081:8082` and `vue-js-app:latest`

Comment: sometimes 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost matters when start the service in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose):

**Publish or expose port (-p, --expose)**

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
```

> This binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of
>   the host machine. You can also specify udp and sctp ports. The Docker
>   User Guide explains in detail how to manipulate ports in Docker.

```
$ docker run --expose 80 ubuntu bash
```

> This exposes port 80 of the container without publishing the port to
>   the host system’s interfaces.

And, from the [Docker User Guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/):

> You also saw how you can bind a container’s ports to a specific port
>   using the -p flag. Here port 80 of the host is mapped to port 5000 of
>   the container:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:5000 training/webapp python app.py
```

So, as an example of how to expose the ports you can use:

```
docker container run --restart always -p 8081:8082 -it vue-js-app:latest
```